How to check radio button checked or not from prowindow XAML in to Maptool in arcgispro sdk
I have a radio button as shown below
<controls:ProWindow x:Class="CalloutModule.cProWinCalloutMaker"
    <RadioButton x:Name="rbtWgs" Checked="rbtWgs_Checked" Content="WGS84 Coordinate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="156,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

I want to know whether this radio button is clicked or not in Maptool.I have done below code ,but always shows false in maptool  and don't know why
In maptool code is as shown below
internal class cAdinCalloutmaker : MapTool
{
      protected override Task<bool> OnSketchCompleteAsync(Geometry geometry)
       {
        cProWinCalloutMaker cWin = new cProWinCalloutMaker();
         if (cWin.rbtWgs.IsChecked == true)
             is_wgs_chekced = true;
         else
             is_wgs_chekced = false;
    }
}

